# Voting to close - icon spins but operation seems to time out

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t close question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51454/cant-close-question)

This has happened a couple of times recently.  Vote to close a question (that already has votes to close) - the little loading spinner appears beside 'close', spins for about 30 seconds and then comes back with a message saying that an error has occurred.

(Using Chrome as a browser, just in case that makes a difference).

---

I know this isn't a big deal, but just thought I'd mention it...

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: most of the time, I fixed those kinds with just Ctrl+F5, and then try again.

Comment: I'm occasionally getting the dialog but no radio buttons in Chrome. I have to use FF if I want to vote.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage - I even tried uplugging the browser and giving it a kick.

Comment: @S.Mark -   I also CTRL+F5, but the error remained when trying again.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this too, exactly as described.

We *think* this might be related to the requests per second throttling/limiting we were doing in nginx.

We've now switched to a requests-per-minute type throttling. See if that helps.